# Magento 2 add title to footer links block

Tags: magento2, layout, footer

I have tried to add a h3 header to the footer links block using the approach outlined here:

[Adding title to cms footer block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115048/adding-title-to-cms-footer-block)

This looks difficult to maintain and it wasn't quite what I wanted.

I can add a static block with my own links and probably get an easier to maintain solution, however, I would prefer to do it the Magento2 way.

It is possible to specify a template for the links block and I can do this but not be able to pull through the actual links.

```
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::html/custom.phtml</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="glossary">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Delivery and returns</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">delivery-information</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="deliveryinfo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Glossary</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">glossary</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Can anyone help with an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Have you seen this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93632/70343?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a text block in default.xml:

```
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="footer_links_title" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                    <![CDATA[<h3>More in this store</h3>]]>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```